# Pan Tool Algorithm being very jumpy

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

Looking for a bit of help to see how I can make this algorithm a little better. So I have some code for a pan tool that moves the camera based on the user dragging the mouse to move the camera around. However it is really jumpy unless it is done in really short drags. I.e. the objects in the scene appear to vibrate, which is more likely to be the camera and canvas 'vibrating' rather than the objects themselves.

The code works by toggling a `dragging` boolean using the `SystemEvent` methods `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` and assigns a `MouseStart` Vector3 in world coordinates and also a `CameraStart` Vector3.

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData EventData)
{
    if (!dragging)
    {
        dragging = true;
        MouseStart = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y, 0f);
        CameraStart = TheCamera.transform.position;
    }
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData EventData)
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        dragging = false;
    }
}
```

Then in the update loop while the `dragging` variable is true, `xChange` and `yChange` float values are determined based on the current mouse position compared to the original mouse position, the camera position is then adjusted according to these. My thought process was that because it is relative to a fixed `MouseStart` (because it is only changed in the single frame where the pointer is clicked and dragging = 0) that if I were to drag and then say keep the mouse still, there would be no change in coordinates as it'd be repeatedly putting the Camera in the same position. The full code looks like this:

```
private bool dragging;

private string CurrentTool;

private ButtonController[] DrawingTools;

public Camera TheCamera;

public Vector3 MouseStart;
public Vector3 CameraStart;

public float sensitivity;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    TheCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
    DrawingTools = FindObjectsOfType<ButtonController>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    for (int i = 0; i < DrawingTools.Length; i++)
    {
        if (DrawingTools[i].Pressed)
        {
            CurrentTool = DrawingTools[i].gameObject.name;
        }
    }

    if (dragging && CurrentTool == "PanTool Button")
    {
        float xChange;
        float yChange;
        Vector3 MousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if (MousePosition.x > MouseStart.x)
        {
            xChange = -Mathf.Abs(MousePosition.x - MouseStart.x);
        }
        else
        {
            xChange = Mathf.Abs(MousePosition.x - MouseStart.x);
        }

        if (MousePosition.y > MouseStart.y)
        {
            yChange = -Mathf.Abs(MousePosition.y - MouseStart.y);
        }
        else
        {
            yChange = Mathf.Abs(MousePosition.y - MouseStart.y);
        }

        TheCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(CameraStart.x + xChange*sensitivity, CameraStart.y + yChange*sensitivity, CameraStart.z);
    }
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData EventData)
{
    if (!dragging)
    {
        dragging = true;
        MouseStart = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y, 0f);
        CameraStart = TheCamera.transform.position;
    }
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData EventData)
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        dragging = false;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Just to clarify this is a 2d environment

Comment: I suspect the jitter is due to the depth difference between the original and new mouse vectors. Perhaps you could create a plane on which the original grab position exists (at the time of grab), and project the new mouse vector from the camera on to that plane. Your camera would then track the new mouse position *along that plane*, but not along the plane's normal. The plane could be either 1) parallel to the view frustum's tangent, or 2) parallel to the x/y, x/z, or y/z plane or 3) arbitrary based on the situation. Assuming the first option, you would end up with a true screen-space pan.

Comment: @cwharris not entirely certain what you’re referring to with this. Feel like I should clarify that this is a 2d environment I’ll make that clear In the question

Comment: Ah, sorry. That probably isn't the issue then, since you're converting Vector2 => Vector3 (which will use 0 for y). Can you elaborate on the motion you see when the camera jitters?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the Camera from which you are determining the world position of the mouse is being updated every frame *according to the world position of the mouse*, which causes a feedback loop (and therefore noise + jitter).

You can reduce noise from the feedback loop by smoothing the Camera's movement over time (effectively a low pass), or try to remove the feedback loop entirely by altering your calculations so the camera position and target position (mouse) don't rely on each other - although I'm not sure how to go about that if it's actually possible for your intent.

Check out [Vector3.SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html).

> Gradually changes a vector towards a desired goal over time.
>
> The vector is smoothed by some spring-damper like function, which will
>   never overshoot. The most common use is for smoothing a follow camera.